# does "already" refers to a time before the present? does it means in the previous articles?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

does "already" refers to a time before the present? does it means in the previous articles?

> The investigation was held, but the results were negative. In an
>   appended note to the doctors' report in the New York Tribune, the
>   editor (Horace Greeley) observes: The doctors, **as has already
>   appeared in our columns**, commenced with the assumption that the
>   origin of the "rapping" sounds must be physical, and their primary
>   cause the volition of the ladies aforesaid—in short, that these ladies
>   were "The Rochester impostors." They appear, therefore, in the above
>   statement, as the prosecutors of an impeachment, and ought to have
>   selected other persons as judges and reporters of the trial . It is
>   quite probable that we shall have another version of the matter.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More specifically, it probably refers to previous columns, or articles, written by Greeley himself.